# How do I view the Java Log?

Tags: java, logging

I have a jsp project where I using the java.util.logging.Logger class to log information. At the moment my code is logging exceptions using this class, however, i would like to view the data written this log. How do I do that?

Comment: what's wrong with `tail -f yourlogfile.log`

Answer (score 6):

It depends how your logging is set up.

In general, it will either be in your server log (for example, for Tomcat, they're in the Tomcat home directory under the `logs` directory), or in a file that's been configured for the app.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to configure the logging output to write into a file (or the console). You can then [tail](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) the file to keep up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your `Logger` class you have to add Handler to enable writing this somewhere.
For Example if you want to write this to a file use the `FileHandler`

```
logger.addHandler(new FileHandler("mylog.log");
```

Refer to the Handler documentation for more infos: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

As the anonymous horse said, there are lots of tools for doing this.

But if you want to do it *within* a Java application, then there are two approaches:

- You could use something like the Apache Commons [`Tailer`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) class to read stuff written to the end of the log file.
- You could create your subclass of [`java.util.logging.Handler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) to process the log events before they reach the log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Logging API then you can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/jlogviewer/ - it accepts .log or .xml